# Finding a Sequences Limit

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_1$>$x_2$ be arbitrary real numbers and $x_n$=$x_{n-1}/3 + 2(x_{n-2})/3$ for all n>2.  Find the formula for $x_n$ and its limit.

I used induction to show that the sequence is strictly increasing, but I couldn't really get beyond that, I'm not sure what to do.  Honestly I'm not even sure what finding the formula for $x_n$ is.  Any help?  Hints are appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: Note that if $x_1 =2$, $x_2 = 1$, then $x_3 = 5/3$ and $x_4 = 11/9$ is smaller than $x_3$.

Comment: $x_n$ is defined as a weighted average of the two predecessors. Hence it will always fall between the two predecessors. With that property there is no way the sequence could be strictly increasing.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Use the classical way : the characteristic equation being given by $$r^2=\frac13 r+\frac23$$ its roots are $r_1=-\frac23$ , $r_2=1$ so the general solution is simply $$x_n=c_1 \left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)^n+c_2$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Rewrite as 
$$x_n-x_{n-1}=-\frac{2}{3}(x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}).\tag{1}$$
Let $y_n=x_n-x_{n-1}$. We can find a simple expression for $y_n$ in terms of $y_2=x_2-x_1$.

Then we can express $x_n$ as the sum of a finite geometric series (hint, telescoping) and the limit as the sum of an infinite geometric series.

The expression (1) shows that $(x_n)$ is neither an increasing nor a decreasing sequence.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
x_n&=\frac{x_{n-1}}3+\frac{2x_{n-2}}3\\
3x_n&=x_{n-1}+2x_{n-2}\\
3x_n-3x_{n-1}&=2x_{n-1}+2x_{n-2}\\
x_n-x_{n-1}&=-\frac23(x_{n-1}-x_{n-2})\\
\Delta x_n&=-\frac23 \Delta x_{n-1}\\
&=\left(-\frac23\right)^2 \Delta x_{n-2}\\
&=\left(-\frac23\right)^3 \Delta x_{n-3}\\
&\vdots\\
&=\left(-\frac23\right)^{n-1} \Delta x_{1}\\
\Rightarrow\Delta x_r&=\left(-\frac23\right)^{r-1} \Delta x_{1}\\
\end{align}$$

Summing from $r=n$ down to $1$ by telescoping, and put $x_0=a,x_1=b$:
$$\begin{align}
x_n-x_1&=-\frac23\left[\frac{1-(-\frac23)^{n-1}}{1-(-\frac23)}\right](x_1-x_0)\\
&=-\frac25\left[1-\left(-\frac23\right)^{n-1}\right](x_1-x_0)\\
x_n&=b-\frac25\left[1-\left(-\frac23\right)^{n-1}\right](b-a)\\
&=\frac15(3b+2a)+\frac25\left(-\frac23\right)^{n-1}(b-a)\qquad \blacksquare
\end{align}$$

As $n\to\infty$,
$$x_n\to\frac15(3b+2a)\qquad \blacksquare$$